# How to parse from this skill set to php?

Tags: php, json, linkedin-api

```
{"linkedin":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n
<skills total=\"11\">\n  
<skill>\n    
    <id>1<\/id>\n    
    <skill>\n      
        <name>C#<\/name>\n    
    <\/skill>\n  
<\/skill>\n  
<skill>\n    
    <id>2<\/id>\n    
    <skill>\n      
        <name>C<\/name>\n    
    <\/skill>\n  
<\/skill>\n  
........................
........................


$id =  getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'id');
      $fname = getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'first-name');
      $lname = getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'last-name');
      $pictureurl = getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'picture-url');
      $email = getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'email-address');
$headline = getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'headline'); 
$summary = getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'summary');  

    $interests=getTextBetweenTags($user_profile['linkedin'], 'interests'); 

$user_profile_skills = $OBJ_linkedin->profile('~/skills:(id,skill:(name))');  

$stringData = json_encode($user_profile_skills);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($stringData->linkedin);
```

How to retrive each value from it using php?. This is the JSON encoded form of skill set getting from linkedin. I am new to these kind of things. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an XML document inside your JSON object, so we need to do two things.

[Decode the JSON](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonString);
```

Use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to parse the XML.

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_string($obj->linkedin);
```

As long as the XML is correctly formatted you will be able to process it as your needs dictate using SimpleXML. Further information on SimpleXML can be found here: http://php.net/simplexml

Comment: Thanks for your faster reply. Is the above code in correct xml formate?. The above code will be the output json_decode. When I tried your code it gives a warning .Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Demo\xml.php on line 8.I am new this. So I don't know anything about it

Comment: If the JSON couldn't be decoded `json_decode` returns `null`. That means that when we try and access the `linkedin` property it throws the error you're getting. The root cause of this problem is that you're not getting correctly formatted JSON, or something similar. Could you post the rest of the code in your question? And possibly also the string that we're hoping was JSON?

Comment: please see the edited Question. I added your code too. $stringData gives the json type format when I write it to a text file

Comment: First thing: you've used `json_encode` instead of `json_decode`. If that doesn't do the trick, we could do with a little more context as to what the `$OBJ_linkedin` object is an instance of.